# Excel formula to add up the number of times a search term is detected

Tags: excel, search, formula, sumproduct

I am looking for a formula to count the number of times a chemical name appears in a text string held in an Excel cell. The chemical names are stored in a named list. The problem is that the text in which I am searching for the chemical name is not always formatted well and the chemical may have a punctuation before or after the chemical name and sometimes the space between the chemical and the next word has been omitted.

I have a formula that will find and count the occurrence a chemical name from a named list. In the formula I have asked it to look for words separated by a space before and after, as I don't want to pick up text that may form part of another word.  However, sometimes there is punctuation before or after the  the chemical name which is causing a problem. eg it will find `cypermethrin` but not `cypermethrin.` I can't seem to work out how to put together in the same formula a search that pulls out the chemical name when it is separated by spaces and when it has punctuation before or after word.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(NOT(ISERR(SEARCH(" "&name& " "," "&DATAENTRYPAGE!$CX2&" ")))*{1})
```

The chemical name can be anywhere in the sentence. I have added a space at the beginning and end of the text string so if the chemical name appears at the beginning or end of the sentence it would be picked out by the above formula. I need to add another search to the above that can pick out the chemical with either punctuation before and after. Help much appreciated

Comment: Add three searches? This sounds like a job better suited to a text editor with Regex capability

Comment: I put your second paragraph in cell A10 then used this formula which returned "2"
=(LEN(A10)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A10,"cypermethrin",""))) / LEN("cypermethrin")

Comment: @Jan, that overlooks the OPs requirement to count whole words only

Comment: @reeder. You could sanitize your strings first, by replacing punctuation with spaces.  Either embedded into your formula,  or as a separate formula in another cell.